# Setting selected option value from dynamically created combobox option values

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var myComboBox = $("#myCombo");
 for (i = 4; i < checked; i++) {
     myComboBox.append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
 }
 myComboBox.selectedIndex = 0;
```

when myComboBox is > 0 I want to select first option so I tried with `myComboBox.selectedIndex = 0;` But using that nothing changed, so I tried with

```
myComboBox.prop('selectedIndex', 0); and
myComboBox[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

nothing works, or at least text is not changed on combobox.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @RahilWazir nope, I'm using $('#cmbSystemK > option').length to determine size and if it's larger than 0 I want to select to first  combobox item

Comment: And wheres the code in your question?

Comment: what code? that's irelevant as far as I can see, if you want I will update with  $('#myCombo > option').length;

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark an option as selected:

```
myComboBox.find("option:first").attr("selected","selected")
```

You can also select an option based on value:

```
myComboBox.val(4)//if you have an option with a value of 4, it will be selected
```